# Take 2 photos and merge them in swift 3

Tags: image, merge, swift3

In swift 3, I would like to merge two images into a single combined image, like so:

[image: this]

The idea is to pick 2 photos from library or take them with camera.  But then having done so, how can the two images be combined together programmatically as shown in the picture above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simplest way to merge 2 photos in single ImageView:

For Example:

```
    let LeftImage = UIImage(named: "LeftImage.png")
    let RightImage = UIImage(named: "RightImage.png")

    let size = CGSize(width: LeftImage!.size.width, height: LeftImage!.size.height + RightImage!.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)

    LeftImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:size.width/2, height: size.height))
    RightImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: size.width/2, y: 0, width:size.width, height: size.height))

    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    MergeImageView.image = newImage
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add two `UIImageView` in one `UIView` and then give the constraints to both the `UIImageView`.

Another Way,
Select two images and then create one CGContext and draw both the images in one and get a single context and take a snapshot of it and add to your `UIImageView`.

Comment: Do you know maybe how to make picture is presented on another view controller after taking picture with custom view camera ?

Comment: When you capture image then you will receive image in its delegate method store it and pass the image or access it from the file written in image.